# Localhost-only pseudo-distributed hadoop installation

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to make a pseudo-distributed Hadoop installation on my Gentoo machine. I want nothing to be visible from the outside network - e.g. jobtracker and namenode web interfaces - localhost:50030 and localhost:50070. However, I noticed that I can access these from within my home network.

How do I restrict all daemons to listen to localhost only?

I've used the configuration suggested by Hadoop:

core-site.xml

```
 1 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 2 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
 3 
 4 <!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
 5 
 6 <configuration>
 7     <property>
 8         <name>fs.default.name</name>
 9         <value>hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000</value>
10     </property>
11 </configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
 1 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 2 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
 3 
 4 <!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
 5 
 6 <configuration>
 7 <property>
 8 <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
 9 <value>127.0.0.1:9001</value>
10     </property>
11 </configuration>
```

I also enforced IPv4 (taken from this [quide](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/)):

hadoop-env.sh

```
export HADOOP_OPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Comment: Why don't you just block the ports on the firewall? What is in your /etc/hosts?

Comment: I was wandering if there are dedicated setting for this. Besides new ports seem to be opening for other services spawned after the daemons start. I'll have to continuously monitor them all in order to block them. But thankfully ports 90000 and 90001 are only listening to localhost as specified by the configs.
My /etc/hosts contains these two lines:
`1 127.0.0.1 localhost no-problems`
`2 ::1 localhost`

Comment: I solved my problem by writing this [script](http://pastebin.com/nwQLL5wU). It requires root permissions though.

Comment: Doesn't the script block all the ports related to Java.

Comment: Yes, there are other problems too, I am still looking for an alternative. I don't know how to filter the needed ports, so I just filtered the Java ones. Moreover, if new ports are open after startup, this will not block them. And if ports are closed, the flush command (when `hadoop-mask -u`) wont work and the rule will stay. You'll have to remove it manually - the faster solution `iptables -F` will also remove all other rules, breaking your configuration...